# What is the ImageMagick .NET function for command line "-dispose None"?

Tags: imagemagick

I use this "-dispose" function on the command line, wondering what the .NET equivalent is so I can use the "dispose" functionality on a MagickImageCollection object.

Answer (score 1):

There is no method for this on the MagickImageCollection. You will need to set the `-dispose` (gif dispose method) on each individual image. Below is an example of how you could do that.

```C#
using (MagickImageCollection images = new MagickImageCollection())
{
  images.Add("first.png");
  images.Add("secpnd.png");
  foreach (MagickImage image in images)
  {
    image.GifDisposeMethod = GifDisposeMethod.None;
  }

  images.Write("output.gif");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try and let you know how this works.